# How to does one load Google Apps Script UDFs for use in Google Sheets from an Add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, user-defined-functions, custom-function, google-apps-script-addon

I'm developing an add-on with a large group of spreadsheet functions. These have been divided up into a number of different sections and have been stored in different files within the add-on's file tree. I have in mind a menu system with checkboxes tying it all together so that one may load one but not the other, or one and a number of others.

That's the idea. This issue is, how does one actually achieve this? How do you say to Sheets (or whatever the subsystem is that controls this sort of thing), "Hey, see this .gs file full of functions? Load it!"?

Related to that is the further refinement, which would be cool if achievable, of being able to unload a block of functions, that is, "Hey, see this file full of functions you loaded 20 minutes ago? Unload 'em!"

So is there a mechanism for loading UDFs from an add-on? Or is this something we'll see in Google Apps Script v6?

Comment: By default, all functions are loaded; especially, if it's used in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

On the Google Sheets lingo the UDF are called [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

On Google Document Editors (Documents, Sheets, Slides) custom menus can't include real check-boxes but you could create "dynamic menus" with an icon or character that shows which feature is turned on/off or use a HTML Service dialog or sidebar to use real check-boxes.

Custom Functions are defined on the global scope, so all of them are public functions all the time. You could avoid having "all the custom functions" as "public custom functions" by using few custom functions as gateways to "private custom functions". Something like the following:

```
function myCustomFunction(choosen){
  var localfunctions = {
    a:function localfunction1(){ return 'one result'},
    b:function localfunction2(){ return 'another result'}
  }
  return  localfunctions[choosen]()
}
```

Real private functions has underscore as the last character of the function name. Your "public custom function" could call them instead of using local functions.

Another alternative is to put your custom functions on an external project and enable it as an API. For details about enabling an Apps Script project as an API see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#step_1_deploy_the_script_as_an_api_executable

Comment: Could you point me to some documentation about "custom functions on an external project and enable it as an API"?

Comment: @bugmagnet No exactly what you are asking for, but the link that I just added cover an important step in the process.